# Subdomain to folder universal rule

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want link any of subdomain to folder and save path after url.
 For example, `sms-rassilka-reklama-barnaul.mirsms.ru/somefile.txt` need to be open in folder `/cities/barnaul/somefile.txt`

But my code with alphabetic part not to work.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?sms-rassilka-reklama-([a-z]+)\.mirsms\.ru$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/cities/%1/$1 [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /cities/%1/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?sms-rassilka-reklama-([a-z]+)\.mirsms\.ru$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/cities/%1/$1 [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /cities/%1/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Because your first capture was www not your word

Comment: Returns 404, folder not found (